Does DuckDB Block Reads when writes are in progress in a single process?
Does DuckDB Block Reads when writes are in progress in a single process or does it allow reads concurrent using MVCC when writes are in progress?

DuckDB allows fully concurrent reads and writes within a single process – see the Concurrency page for details. Reads are not blocked. In case of a transaction runs into a conflict, a Transaction conflict error is thrown, the transaction is aborted and its changes are rolled back.
